# Transmission started to detect torrents bigger than they are

Tags: transmission, file-size

When I add a torrent the program works fine but after a few minutes it increases the value of total size. Right now I am downloading a torrent of size 5.08 GB, but the program detects it as 5.45 GB.

What may cause that kind of problem and how do I check whether files downloaded correctly?

Comment: I have the same problem I am downloading path of exile torrent and the file is 4.26GB(not GiB) as shown everywhere but the the status is showing that 5.03 GB(not GiB) is already downloaded and only 50% is downloaded yet and it still keeps downloading??!!! Weird never had this problem before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the unit is the same? Maybe Transmissions is not using **GiB** units?

---

It happens, that 5.45 **GB** = 5.08 **GiB** <--- Note the "i".

The difference between GB (gigabytes) and GiB (gibibytes) is that GB are based on power of 10, and GiB are based on power of 2.

```
1 GB  = 1000 MB
1 GiB = 1024 MiB
```

and, subsequently

```
1 MB  = 1000 kB
1 MiB = 1024 kiB
```

**GiB** is not a SI unit, though SI standard *recommends* to use it for data size. There is a short article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte and there is a detailed explanation of this idea: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix

Note that 5.45 GB = 5450000000 B = 5.08 GiB, so if Transmission uses GB instead of GiB, then everything is okay ;)

Comment: Yes, I haven't noticed that in torrent description GiB used, but Transmission uses GB. Thanks a lot!